# Is the Invisible Man present in these scenes?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-man-2020

In *The Invisible Man* (2020), the audience is not always aware if Adrian is present or not in the scene, for obvious reasons. However, we learn later that:

> His brother is also using an invisible suit, at least in the last confrontation scene in James' house.

So I assume Adrian was in most scenes, including:

- slapping the girl;
- in his own house when Cecilia  is hiding;
- in the sister attack at the restaurant;
- in the mental hospital attack;
- during the rain chase in the parking lot.

If so, how could Adrian be tied up and captive in his own house moments after the last two events?

Comment: Did the movie show how much time had passed between the brother getting killed and the Adrian's house being raided? I imagine Adrian would have time to get home and tie himself up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has never been stated how many invisibility suits there are, for all we know, there are at least three:

1. Andrian is wearing one suit, which has been partially damaged by Cecilia during their mental hospital struggle.
2. Andrian's brother is wearing a second suit, which is intact.
3. Cecilia finds the third one, hides it and wears it to kill Andrian.

What happens in a timeline right after Andrian and Cecilia's struggle is most likely:

1. Andrian calls Tom to attack Sydney, Andrian cannot facilitate this attack due to his own suit has become partially damaged.
2. Tom carries out the attack and gets killed in process.
3. Andrian learns about Tom's death somehow and pretends to be kidnapped. As the time elapsed between Andrian learns Tom's death and SWAT raids Andrian's mansion is unknown, and Andrian could have hatched this kidnapped scenario as his backup plan, he has plenty of time and resources to stage his own kidnapping.

Comment: I assumed that the mental hospital attack, the chase in the rain and the showdown in James' house where the brother is killed were all the same invisible man - wasn't the suit glitching all the way through these scenes after Cecilia damaged it?

Comment: @Mr_Thyroid, no, Tom's suit has never got any glitch during the fight in James's house.

Comment: Neither was it wet.